# Upgrading ASP.NET MVC Web App from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am looking at upgrading an existing ASP.NET MVC Web App from .NET Framework v4.5 to v.4.7.2.  I was able to find some vague documentation from Microsoft, but there was nothing concrete in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/.  For development I am using VS2019.

Is it recommended to go straight from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.7.2 or would it be wiser to gradually migrate through the point releases 4.5.x, 4.6.x, etc. until I get to 4.7.2?

The application itself is pretty standard so I don't expect many surprises as I migrate, but I would like to know if there is a "correct" way to go about the migration.

Comment: I would recommend looking at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/) and see if there are any changes regarding your program usages. Most of the times, problem with specific nuget packages may appear as the are not supporting the latest .net framework. see if that is the case aswell.

Comment: @arlanschouwstra I will definitely take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this a few times now and I think overall it has just been easy enough to just rip off the band-aid and go straight to the Target Framework you are looking to upgrade to.